# Convert int8_t to std::string

Tags: c++, c++98

Is this correct for all C++ compilers? Or should I cast to int first instead?

```
int8_t i = -128; 
std::string = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>((int16_t)i)
```

Comment: Out of interest, why do you even need the cast?

Comment: @NPE:  Probably because `int8_t` is a `(unsigned) char`

Comment: @NPE Because on my compiler int8_t is defined as a signed char. This results in, for example, the value of 30 being interpreted as ascii 30 which is " " not "30".

Comment: It is correct, now feel free to blame lame C and C++ committee who dediced it would be a `typedef` instead of a proper built-in type with integral semantics.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `std::to_string` function to do this:

```
 std::int8_t i = -128; 
 std::string s=std::to_string(i);
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string

NOTE:

I assumed C++11 because fixed width types where only added in C++11

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

### edit

If this is not C++11 (and you are getting the typedef form somewhere else (C99?)) then you can just provide the source type as a template parameter.

```
 std::string str=boost::lexical_cast<std::string, int>(i);
```

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm#synopsis

Comment: But that will only work on C++11 compatible compilers, right?

Comment: @Baz int8_t is only C++11 too.

Comment: I'm using the one defined in stdint.h C99.

Comment: @Baz, ok see my amendment, `lexical_cast` has a target and source template parameter.

Comment: @Baz - did boost integer.hpp make it into C++11? If boost::int8_t is the same as std::int8_t (and I suspect it is), then older compilers can use boost integer.hpp to get those numeric types (int8_t, uint8_t, etc).